# How to use watchdog to run the script every time a file is modified with a certain word?

Tags: python, watchdog

So the script below looks for keywords inside the HTML file and writes the values of the found keywords in file `style.css`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
keyword = {
"row": '''
    .row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex; 
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    }'''
    #etc
        }   

with open('index.html', 'r') as file:
   with open('style.css', 'a') as newfile:
      lines = file.readlines()
      for line in lines:
         if 'class="' in line:
            to_replace = line.split('"')[1].split()
            to_replace = OrderedDict.fromkeys(to_replace)
            for key in to_replace:
                if key in keyword:
                    newfile.write(keyword[key])
                    keyword[key] = ''
```

The HTML file:

```
<div class="row">some content</div>
<div class="row">some content2</div> etc
```

Output in `style.css`:

```
.row {
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex; 
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin-right: -15px;
        margin-left: -15px;
        }
```

Notice: `row` written in html twice but displayed in styles only once.

**How can I run the code every time the file `index.html` is saved AND a certain keyword from the dictionary is found** (using the watchdog `on_modified` event)**?
and also, how to prevent duplication of css commands in `style.css`?**

Comment: Which operating system do you intend on running this on? Different OS'es have different hooks for this. Unless you do `os.stat(file_path)` and check `m_time` on the file. Which won't be completely reliable but it's something.

Comment: @Torxed thank you! it would be much appreciated if you showed both on windows and mac. i just couldn't figure how this watchdog is used..